# how to display future products in opencart

Tags: opencart, future, product

products in open cart script doesn't show up in front end page when i add product and set the date to the future 
am trying to display future products S i want to know how can i do that is there anyway i can do that,i do search a lot for answer to that question but all i found is xml file need vqmod system but it's not working too . so please guys am trying to display future products on homepage
here's then answer which didn't work

```
<modification>
<id><![CDATA[Products with future available date become able to show in store and be purchased]]></id>
<version><![CDATA[1.0.0]]></version>
<vqmver><![CDATA[2.0.0]]></vqmver>
<author><![CDATA[angeloop]]></author>

<file name="catalog/model/catalog/product.php">
  <operation>
    <search position="after"><![CDATA['p.date_added']]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[, 'p.date_available']]></add>
</operation>

<operation>
    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[AND p.date_available <= NOW()]]>  </search>
    <add><![CDATA[]]></add>
</operation>
</file>

<file name="system/library/cart.php">
  <operation>
    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[AND p.date_available <= NOW()]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[]]></add>
  </operation>
</file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a module for it.

Go to the link below

[Coming soon products module for OpenCart](https://webocreation.com/blog/coming-soon-products-module)

Download the modules and set the modules which will show future products or coming soon products